# Procedural cel shaded displacement material

Tags: materials, node-editor, shader-nodes, vector-mapping, toon-shading

I have a material which creates procedural sphere displacement to create a random blob. I want to cel shade the blob, however as far as I can tell this is only possible with EEVEE `Shader to RGB` node, while displacement is only possible in Cycles which can't do cel shading.

I wanted to use the displacement modifier with an `Cloud` image texture, however that doesn't have the `W` value for the seed (I can't find a way to generate unique image textures), and makes the process more convoluted than just a few `Value` nodes.

I haven't looked at geometry nodes the answer might lie there.

TLDR; I want to use cel shading and vector displacement together.

Comment: Any objection to using a displacement modifier instead?

Comment: @RobinBetts that's what I meant in the second paragraph

Comment: Ahh, OK thx for the edit Yes. GN can completely replace the Disp. modifier.. with a seed, and more control in other ways, too.